# Per-Viewport Settings vs Global Settings

Tags: interface, 3d-view

When there are multiple viewports active in the UI, it seems that some settings apply per-viewport, while others apply globally.

**Examples of per-viewport settings:**

- shading mode (wireframe, solid, rendered, etc...)
- transform manipulators
- Visible layers (after finding the "unlock camera and layers" button)

**Examples of global settings:**

- Object interaction mode (i.e. object mode, edit mode, weight paint, etc..)
- Pivot point
- Edit mode's selection type (i.e. vertex, edge, or face)
- Edit mode's visible/hidden vertices/edge/faces

Is there any way to get the global settings applied per-viewport? For example, could one get one viewport in edit mode while another is in object mode? Is it possible to have one viewport in edit mode selecting vertices, while another is selecting faces?

Comment: My question is more general than that one. The ability to unlock layers addresses part of it, but I think the answer to _this_ will be about telling the difference between options that have an "unlock button" and those which don't.

Comment: I'm bummed that this is considered a duplicate :(... Would the question be better if I ripped out all but the last two sentences?

Comment: I just voted to reopen. I don't think the answer to the other question fully addresses your question, though the reverse may be true.